# Delete columns with a certain condition except if it is name is contained in a particular list

Tags: python, dataframe, conditional-statements

I am analysing datasets of different days.
There are hundreds of variables in the dataframe and many of them are constants (variables that have the same value for all the observations in the dataset). However, these "constants" variables change according to the day of the analysis.

Example: Maybe on day 1 variables "A", "C", "K", "M" are constants but on day 2 variables "B", "C", "M", "S", "W" are constants.

I want to remove these constants, except if they are variables that are considered important for the visualisation afterwards. For example, except the variables named "B", "F" and "K".

What I am using now to remove ALL constants is:

```
df_describe = df.describe()
constants = df_describe.columns[df_describe.loc["std"]<0.01]
df.drop(labels=constants, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

What I need is a code to add something like:

```
Except if variable is named "B", "F" and "K"
```

So, for the example of day 1 I would like to remove "A", "C" and "M" and using my current code I am removing "A", "C", "K", "M"

Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can remove columns names you want to keep (B,F and K) from constants like below

```py
constants = list(set(constants)-set(["B", "F", "K"]))
```

then drop constants from df

Comment: I tested the example with 2 variables but  got the following error: TypeError: set expected at most 1 arguments, got 2

Comment: sorry forgot the "[ ]" plz check now